# How can I call the next view function using react-step-builder?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am working with react-step-builder to build a multi-step form. The code works, when the default next or prev button that is built into the step builder is clicked. What I want to now is call next or prev from within my own code instead of the default buttons. I want to customize the call.

here is my setup

MainApp

```js
import React from "react";

import { Steps, Step } from "react-step-builder";
import Step1, {Step2, FinalStep} from "./steps";

import EnterPLU from "../components/PLUViews/EnterPLUView"
import PLUProductView from "../components/PLUViews/PLUProductView"

import { Button, Col, Row } from "antd";

const Navigation = (props) => {
  console.log({ props });
  return (
    <Row align="center">
      <Col>
        <Button type="primary" onClick={props.prev} style={{ marginRight: 10 }}>
          Previous
        </Button>
      </Col>
      <Col>
        <Button type="primary" onClick={props.next}>
          Next
        </Button>
      </Col>
    </Row>
  );
};

function AddPLUApp() {
  const config = {
    navigation: {
      component: Navigation, // a React component with special props provided automatically
      location: "after" // or before
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="AddPLUApp">
     
      <Steps config={config}>
        <Step component={EnterPLU} />
        <Step component={PLUProductView} />
        <Step component={FinalStep} />
      </Steps>
    </div>
  );
}

export default AddPLUApp;
```

Currently the form moves from step 1 to 2 with a next button defined above. Then I have a keypad view that I use in step 1, EnterPLU. Here is my keypad

```js
import React, { useReducer, useEffect } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import styled from "styled-components";

import "../../css/keypad.css";

const numbers = Array.from({ length: 6 }, () => Math.floor(Math.random() * 8));
const lengthOfNumbers = numbers.length;

function KeyPad(props){
  const [values, dispatch] = useReducer((state, { type, value }) => {
    switch (type) {
      case "add":
        return state + value;
      case "enter":
        // check if the order is right
        const stateCopy = [...state];
        const lengthOfState = stateCopy.length;
        const toCheck = [...numbers].splice(0, lengthOfState);
        if (toCheck.toString() === stateCopy.toString()) {
          if (lengthOfState === lengthOfNumbers) {
              console.log("final value ", values)
            return "Success!";
          } else {
            console.log("final value ", values)
            return state + value;
          }
          console.log("final value ", state + value, values)
          console.log("The current props is : ", props)

        } else {
          // otherwise, reset the state to an empty array
          console.log("final value ",state + value, values, props)

          return [];
        }

        console.log("Enter button pressed")
        
      case "clear":
        return [];
      default:
        return state;
    }
  


  }, []);

//   useEffect(() => { 
//     // console.log("Keypad activated. values ", values)
//     })      

  // to stop the user from using the buttons.
  const disabled = values.length === numbers.length || values === "Success!";

  return (
    <div className="Keypad">
      {/* <Container> */}
        <KeyPadNumbers>{values}</KeyPadNumbers>
        <Buttons>
          <StyledButton
            disabled={disabled}
            onClick={() =>
              dispatch({
                type: "add",
                value: 1
              })
            }
          >
            1
          </StyledButton>
          <StyledButton
            disabled={disabled}
            onClick={() =>
              dispatch({
                type: "add",
                value: 2
              })
            }
          >
            2
          </StyledButton>
          <StyledButton
            disabled={disabled}
            onClick={() =>
              dispatch({
                type: "add",
                value: 3
              })
            }
          >
            3
          </StyledButton>
        </Buttons>
        <Buttons>
          <StyledButton
            disabled={disabled}
            onClick={() =>
              dispatch({
                type: "add",
                value: 4
              })
            }
          >
            4
          </StyledButton>
          <StyledButton
            disabled={disabled}
            onClick={() =>
              dispatch({
                type: "add",
                value: 5
              })
            }
          >
            5
          </StyledButton>
          <StyledButton
            disabled={disabled}
            onClick={() =>
              dispatch({
                type: "add",
                value: 6
              })
            }
          >
            6
          </StyledButton>
        </Buttons>
        <Buttons>
          <StyledButton
            disabled={disabled}
            onClick={() =>
              dispatch({
                type: "add",
                value: 7
              })
            }
          >
            7
          </StyledButton>
          <StyledButton
            disabled={disabled}
            onClick={() =>
              dispatch({
                type: "add",
                value: 8
              })
            }
          >
            8
          </StyledButton>
          <StyledButton
            disabled={disabled}
            onClick={() =>
              dispatch({
                type: "add",
                value: 9
              })
            }
          >
            9
          </StyledButton>
        </Buttons>
        <Buttons>
          <ClearButton
            disabled={values.length === 0 || values === "Success!"}
            onClick={() =>
              dispatch({
                type: "clear"
              })
            }
          >
            clear
          </ClearButton>
          <StyledButton
            disabled={disabled}
            onClick={() =>
              dispatch({
                type: "add",
                value: 0
              })
            }
          >
            0
          </StyledButton>
          <EnterButton
            disabled={values.length === 0 || values === "Success!"}
            onClick={() =>
              dispatch({
                type: "enter"
              })
            }
          >
            enter
          </EnterButton>
        </Buttons>
      {/* </Container> */}
    </div>
  );
};

const Container = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: 50px auto;
  width: 300px;
  padding: 24px 16px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
`;

const StyledButton = styled.button`
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 300;
  border: none;
  margin: 8px 16px;
  outline: none;

//   :hover {
//     border-radius: 50%;
//     box-shadow: #506ce8 0 0 1px 1px;
//   }
`;

const ClearButton = styled(StyledButton)`
  font-size: 1em;
  margin: 8px;

//   :hover {
//     border-radius: 50%;
//     box-shadow: red 0 0 1px 1px;
//   }
`;

const EnterButton = styled(ClearButton)`
//   :hover {
//     border-radius: 50%;
//     box-shadow: green 0 0 1px 1px;
//   }
`;

const Buttons = styled.div`
  margin: 0 auto;
`;

const KeyPadNumbers = styled.div`
  width: 180px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 1px solid #d5d5d5;
  height: 50px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  font-size: 20px;
`;


export default KeyPad;
```

The code works but I want to change the view with when the enter button on the keypad is pressed. So instead of changing the view with default next button, I can change it with enter button.

How could I have achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside your `EnterPLU` component, you need to call `props.next()` function to move to the next step. If you want to call this function inside `KeyPad` component, pass that function down to `KeyPad` component.

`<KeyPad {/* your other props*/} next={props.next} />`

Then inside your `KeyPad` component, update the `onClick` handler of your `EnterButton` component and call the function you are receiving from the parent component.

```
<EnterButton
  disabled={values.length === 0 || values === "Success!"}
  onClick={() => {
    dispatch({ type: "enter" });
    props.next();
  }}
>
  enter
</EnterButton>
```